If $A\hookrightarrow X$ is an embedding and $X\hookrightarrow Y$ is a compact embedding, then $A\hookrightarrow Y$ is also compact?
Similarly, the question asked in If X↪Y
is compact and A⊂X
is closed, then A↪Y
is also compact?:
Let $A=(A,\|\cdot\|_A)$, $X=(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $Y=(Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be Banach spaces such that $X \hookrightarrow Y$, that is, $X$ is continuous embedding in $Y$. In other words, the inclusion map $i: X \longrightarrow Y$ is continous. Suppose further that $i$ is compact operator, that is, $X$ is compactly embedded in $Y$.
If $A\hookrightarrow X$ is an embedding and $X\hookrightarrow Y$ is a  compact embedding:
Question. Is $A\hookrightarrow Y$ an compact embedding?

The composition of a bounded operator and a compact operator is always compact, whether the compact operator is on the left or on the right.

Oh I see. I found this in  Y.A. Abramovich, and C.D. Aliprantis, Problems in Operator Theory (American Mathematical Soc., 2002) problem 2.4.3.
Thanks.
